# Retroactively Calculate Profit

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, reports

I have a client that set up their products without filling in the cost field. They now wish to report an actual profit in Magento and I have set cost for all products. However, I notice the profit is only correct on reporting after this change. Looking at orders, those that were placed prior to the fix have a profit of $0 since it didn't have the cost value to do the calculation. Those are fine.

Is there any way `I can force Magento to update those historic orders in order to get their profits`? I've tried the simple option of doing a "Refresh Stats" but that doesn't change anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Orders in Magento can't be updated after they've been processed.  That's why you're not seeing the cost information update.

You could contact one of the edit orders extension developers from Connect to see if their extension covers this use case.  Worst case would involve doing manual SQL queries but I wouldn't consider that if you're not really comfortable with the table structure and what you'd need to change.